Has the ideal "pairing" $\langle aG, bG\rangle \mapsto abG$ been ruled out conditionally?
Let $G$ be a prime order $Q$ elliptic curve over a prime field of size $P$ which admits the following mapping $f$
$f(aG, bG) = abG$
which can be computed in polynomial time in $\log(PQ)$.
Is the existence of such a thing ruled out assuming ECDLP hardness or a substantially stronger computational assumption?
If such an efficient mapping existed, we would get an easy practical FHE. Clearly such a thing either doesn't exist or is very very difficult to find. Do we have any formalization of this hardness?

@HilderVitorLimaPereira: the corresponding addition operation $g(aG, bG) = aG + bG = (a+b)G$ is easy.

This function would solve the computational Diffie-Hellman problem in polynomial time. We specifically intend to choose cryptographic curves as ones where this problem is hard.

Great, so there is an assumption named after this exact problem. No reducing from another assumption is needed

IIRC, such an "ideal pairing" would also make it possible to solve the discrete log problem in $G$ in subexponential time:
https://crypto.stanford.edu/~dabo/pubs/abstracts/bbf.html

Thanks! Looking into this. Interesting curves would be the ones where DLP is hard but CDH is easy (the gap between them is as large as possible). Apparently this paper put a limit on the difficulty gap between these two.
